Can someone help me center the images in the media query. If I hide the overflow the burger menu doesn't work
Can someone help me center the images in the media query. If I hide the overflow the burger menu doesn't work. I am relatively new to coding and would appreciate. I tried for several days now to find a solution but I just seem to get it right. Either I don't show overflow and the burger menu dosen't work or the images aren't centered.


@media (max-width: 850px) {
  * {
    color: black;
  }

  body {
    background-image: none;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgb(19, 197, 63);
  }

  .toggle_button {
    display: flex;
    left: 25px;
  }

  nav ul {
    height: min-content;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #008b00;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  nav li {
    height: min-content;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  nav ul a {
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: left;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  #toggle_button:checked~ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .Logo {
    top: 4px;
    width: 10%;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 30%;
  }

  .livingroom-image {
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .middle {
    top: 350px;
    left: 175px;
  }

  .badezimmer-image {
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .middle2 {
    top: 150px;
    left: 255px;
  }

  .küche-image {
    top: 190%;
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .middle3 {
    left: 520px;
  }

  .schlafzimmer-image {
    top: 115%;
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .middle4 {
    top: 525px;
    left: 290px;
  }

  .umgebung-image {
    top: 80%;
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .middle5 {
    top: 300px;
    left: 660px;
  }

  .hauswand-image {
    top: 150%;
    left: 35%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .middle6 {
    top: 520px;
    left: 550px;
  }
}
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>FeWO „op Hahnendel“</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- menu top right-->
  <nav>

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_button">
    <label for="toggle_button" class="toggle_button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
      <li><a href="Ausstattung.html">Ausstattung</a></li>
      <li><a href="impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!--Logo-->
  <img class="Logo" src="IMG/logo/Logo.png">

  <!--Wohnzimmer (rund Bild)-->
  <div class="containerRI">
    <div class="container2">
      <a href="Wohnzimmer.html"><img src="IMG/livingroom/WoF.jpg" class="livingroom-image"></a>

      <div class="middle">

        <a class=text1 href="Wohnzimmer.html">Wohnzimmer</a>
      </div>

      <a href="Wohnzimmer.html"></a>
    </div>

    <!--badezimmer-->
    <div class="container3">
      <a href="bathroom.html"><img src="IMG/bathroom/BAG.jpg" class="badezimmer-image"></a>

      <div class="middle2">

        <a class=text2 href="bathroom.html">Badezimmer</a>
      </div>

      <a href="bathroom.html"></a>
    </div>

    <!--küche-->
    <div class="container4">
      <a href="Kitchen.html"><img src="IMG/kitchen/kuechenzeile.jpg" class="küche-image"></a>

      <div class="middle3">

        <a class=text3 href="Kitchen.html">Küche</a>
      </div>

      <a href="Kitchen.html"></a>
    </div>

    <!--schlafzimmer-->
    <div class="container5">
      <a href="Bedroom.html"><img src="IMG/bedroom/bed.JPG" class="schlafzimmer-image"></a>

      <div class="middle4">

        <a class=text4 href="Bedroom.html">Schlafzimmmer</a>
      </div>

      <a href="Bedroom.html"></a>
    </div>

    <!--umgebung-->
    <div class="container6">
      <a href="Enviroment.html"><img src="IMG/enviroment/e1.jpg" class="umgebung-image"></a>

      <div class="middle5">

        <a class=text5 href="Enviroment.html">Umgebung</a>
      </div>

      <a href="Enviroment.html"></a>
    </div>

    <!--hauswand-->
    <div class="container7">
      <a href="Outside.html"><img src="IMG/outside/Terasse.jpg" class="hauswand-image"></a>

      <div class="middle6">

        <a class=text6 href="Outside.html">Aussen</a>
      </div>

      <a href="Outside.html"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="phonePictuers">
    <img src="IMG/bedroom/baufkleber.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>




I think it would help us help you if you could create a minimal reproducible example of the problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
